# How can I verify WordPress nonce from the following code?

Tags: mysql, nonce

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Manage Days
*/


if ( isset($_GET['remove_date']) && isset($_GET['_wpnonce']) ) {
    $delete_date = $_GET['remove_date'];
    $delete_nonce = $_GET['_wpnonce'];

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $delete_nonce, 'holiday_nonce' ) ) {
        die( 'Failed security check' );
    } else {
        $delete_holiday = $wpdb->delete( 
        $wpdb->prefix . 'ab_holidays',
            [ 'staff_id' => $staff_id, 'date' => $delete_date ],
            [ '%d', '%s' ] );
    }

}

get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        $disable_dates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ab_holidays WHERE staff_id = '$staff_id'");

        foreach ( $disable_dates as $disable_date ) {
            $originalDate = $disable_date->date;
            $newDate = date("F j, Y", strtotime($originalDate));

            $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'holiday_nonce' . $originalDate );
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '?remove_date=' . $originalDate . '&_wpnonce=' . $nonce . '" class="delete-holiday"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>' . $newDate . '<br />';
        }
    ?>

<?php
get_footer();
```

> if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $delete_nonce, 'holiday_nonce' ) ) { ....
>   } else { ..... }

This code isn't working....

Comment: What exactly is your question? The [Theme Handbook has a chapter about using nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/using-nonces/), where everything should be explained

Comment: I can't verify nonce in header,  `if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $delete_nonce, 'holiday_nonce' ) ) { ....... }` this code is not working in header

Comment: Please edit your question and make it clear what is it that you are asking about so even people that do not look at your computer can understand it ;) A wall of code can be good in addition to a textual description but it rarely makes a good question by itself

Comment: I have edited my question. The **blockquote** don't working....